# PHP - Laravel 5 get data to html table from 3 SQL database tables with column DATA as headers

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm very new to PHP so please bear with me - this may be completely obvious to you but unfortunately I am pulling my hair out!...
For info I am using Laravel 5.

I want to use data from SQL database tables (teams and user_profiles) to list profile images followed by users names (both stored in the user_profiles table) in columns, below headers that are titled with the relevant team name (stored in the teams table).

I've managed to do this by manually creating a variable for each team in my 'admin' controller, each contains a query to get the data based on the id number in the teams table

**Example of a variable in my admincontroller.php**

```
$team1 = DB::table('user_profiles')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
->join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'user_profiles.teams_id')
->select('users.*', 'user_profiles.*', 'teams.*')
->where(['teams.id' => 1])
->get();
```

**Calling this in the admin.blade.php (trimmed to show 'team 1' only)**

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <h3>Team 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="panel-inner-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 panel-inner-left">

    @foreach ($team1 as $profile)
        <img src="{{ $profile->profile_pic }}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar center-block" />
        <div class="lead text-center">
            <p>{{ $profile->name }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I have considered using a html table, where I have used a foreach to create as many columns as there are rows on the teams table, and populate the table head for each column with the team name. However, what I cannot figure out is how to populate each column with the users_profiles data based on each team - what I have at the moment - which I knew wouldn't work - is the duplicated profile pic and name of user 1 in every column.

Assume user_profiles table has 9 rows, and each user profile row has id, name, and teams_id
AND
teams table has 4 rows, each with teams_id and team_name

**What I have**

```
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|team 1      |   team 2      |   team 3   |   team 4    |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|user 1 img  |  user 1 img   | user 1 img | user 1 img  |
|User 1 name | user 1 name   | user 1 name| user 1 name |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|user 1 img  |  user 1 img   | user 1 img | user 1 img  |
|User 1 name | user 1 name   | user 1 name| user 1 name |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
```

**What I want**

```
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|team 1      |   team 2      |   team 3   |   team 4    |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|user 1 img  |  user 2 img   | user 3 img | user 4 img  |
|User 1 name | user 2 name   | user 3 name| user 4 name |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
|user 5 img  |  user 6 img   | user 7 img | user 8 img  |
|User 5 name | user 6 name   | user 7 name| user 8 name |
|------------|---------------|------------|-------------|
```

Please tell me if I need to give any extra information, any ideas hugely appreciated.

Here is an example dump of `$team1`:

```
Collection {#213 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#219 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "Tom"
      +"email": REMOVED
      +"password": REMOVED
      +"admin": 1
      +"remember_token": REMOVED
      +"created_at": "2017-10-19 18:07:00"
      +"updated_at": "2017-10-19 18:08:38"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"teams_id": 1
      +"profile_pic": "http://laravel.dev/uploads/dartboard.png"
      +"team_name": "Barkers"
      +"venue": "Barker Butts"
      +"venue_post_code": "CV5 9AR"
    }
    1 => {#216 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "John Smith"
      +"email": REMOVED
      +"password": REMOVED
      +"admin": 0
      +"remember_token": REMOVED
      +"created_at": "2017-10-19 18:07:00"
      +"updated_at": "2017-10-19 18:08:38"
      +"user_id": 3
      +"teams_id": 1
      +"profile_pic": "http://laravel.dev/uploads/dartboard.png"
      +"team_name": "Barkers"
      +"venue": "Barker Butts"
      +"venue_post_code": "CV5 9AR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a `dd()` or `var_dump()` of `$team1`?

Comment: added to the question. for info, this also includes data from a 3rd table, 'users', for other purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your teams are going to have the same amout of users then you can add this variables to your controller:

```
// Group all of your teams in a single array
$teams = [
    $team1,
    $team2,
    $team3,
    $team4
];

// Create an array with a length equal
// to the number of necessary rows
$rows = range(0, $team1->count() - 1);
```

Then pass them to your view:

```
return view('someview')->with([
    'teams' => $teams,
    'rows' => $rows
]);
```

And finally use them like:

```
@foreach ($rows as $row)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($teams as $team)
            <td>
                {{ $team[$row]->profile_pic }} <br>
                {{ $team[$row]->name }}
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hopefully this should give you an idea how to achieve what you are trying to build.

I suggest giving the [Laravel's collections documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) a read.

Comment: Thanks @Camilo, I'll give this a go.

Comment: Added some comments in case it wasn't clear how it works.

Comment: using the above, I get an error - property [count] does not exist on this collection instance... :(

Comment: Try replacing `count` with `count()`.

Comment: range() is throwing an error too, expects a minimum of 2 parameters only 1 provided.

Comment: Try replacing `range($team1->count())` with `range(0, $team1->count())`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Camilo. It's not working I'm afraid and its nearly 2am so I'm going try again tomorrow...tried to +1 your answer but my rating is too low...

Comment: No problem. You can leave a comment tomorrow and I'll try to help.

Comment: There was a problem with `range(0, $team1->count())`, try replacing it with `range(0, $team1->count() - 1)` when you can.

Comment: This is perfect @Camilo, thank you for your help - really appreciated!!!