# using group by and count and where query together in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel, so I apologize in advance if my question is simple. I have a table (table1) that has 3 column (ID, V, result), something like this:

```
ID---------v---------result
1----------123---------True
1----------123---------True
1----------123---------false
2----------123---------false
2----------123---------True
2----------123---------error
```

I want to count how many false and Trues, each ID have. like table2:

```
ID--------numOfT---------numOfF--------other
1----------2---------------1------------0
2----------1---------------1------------1
```

I think I should use **group by** and **count** and **where**, something like this: 
$table2 = DB::table('table1')
            ->groupBy('ID')->
            ->count();
but I don't know the exact query.
Any Idea how can I get the table2?

Comment: Tim has given you a specific answer. But if you're interested in deeper learning about the topic, the term to search this site and more generally is: "pivot query".

Comment: Thank you @Watcher. I will search that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one raw MySQL query which would meet your requirements, using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'True'  THEN 1 END) AS numOfT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS numOfF,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN result NOT IN ('True', 'false') THEN 1 END) AS other
FROM table1
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

The corresponding Laravel code might look like this:

```
$result = DB::table('table1')
    ->select('ID',
             DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'True' THEN 1 END) AS numOfT'),
             DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'false' THEN 1 END) AS numOfF'),
             DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN result NOT IN ('True', 'false') THEN 1 END) AS other'))
    ->groupBy('ID')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen , but I get a error that I think it is because of my poor HTML skill, is the "result" a table?

Comment: Your question mentions nothing of an error.  What error is my code giving you?

Comment: I don't think it is because of your code, it is probably because of my HTML code for show the "result".
FatalErrorException in 73759960ec9472cb9df83cffa29f0db8 line 67:
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I don't know/can't control what you do with the above code.  If you have a major problem with your HTML code, maybe you should open another question for that.

Comment: my question is, the output ($result) is a table, right?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840268/php-laravel-5-get-data-to-html-table-from-3-sql-database-tables-with-column-da) to see what is being returned.  The call to `get()` should return a collection in PHP, which you may iterate, row by row.

Comment: It totally works. Thank you so much. @TimBiegeleisen